# Python, Len not counting rows correctly

Tags: python

I have a loop that counts the rows in each sheet of an xls. When i open the xls itself the count is not exactly aligning with what python is returning me.

```
row_counts = []
for sheet in list(data_mapping.keys()):
    row_counts.append(len(data_mapping.get(sheet)))
    print(len(data_mapping.get(sheet)))
```

my counts printed are:

```
65521
65519
65519
65519
65519
65519
65519
65519
65519
65519
65519
25426
```

However when I open up my excel and count my sheet I am getting

```
   65520 , this has a header and data starts on row 3
65520 , no header data starts on row 1
65520 , no header data starts on row 1
65520 , no header data starts on row 1
65520 , no header data starts on row 1
65520, no header data starts on row 1
65520, no header data starts on row 1
65520, no header data starts on row 1
65520, no header data starts on row 1
65520, no header data starts on row 1
65520, no header data starts on row 1
25427, no header data starts on row 1
```

my full code:

```
from io import BytesIO
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import os
import pandas as pd
from os import walk


def process_files(files: list) -> pd.DataFrame:
    file_mapping = {}
    for file in files:
        #data_mapping = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(ZipFile(file).read(Path(file).stem)), sheet_name=None)
        
        archive = ZipFile(file)

        # find file names in the archive which end in `.xls`, `.xlsx`, `.xlsb`, ...
        files_in_archive = archive.namelist()
        excel_files_in_archive = [
            f for f in files_in_archive if Path(f).suffix[:4] == ".xls"
        ]
        # ensure we only have one file (otherwise, loop or choose one somehow)
        assert len(excel_files_in_archive) == 1

        # read in data
        data_mapping = pd.read_excel(
            BytesIO(archive.read(excel_files_in_archive[0])),
            sheet_name=None,
        )

        row_counts = []
        for sheet in list(data_mapping.keys()):
            row_counts.append(len(data_mapping.get(sheet)))
            print(len(data_mapping.get(sheet)))

        file_mapping.update({file: sum(row_counts)})

    frame = pd.DataFrame([file_mapping]).transpose().reset_index()
    frame.columns = ["file_name", "row_counts"]

    return frame


zip_files = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.zip'):
            zip_files.append(os.path.join(root, file))
df = process_files(zip_files)
```

does anyone have an idea on what im doing wrong?

Comment: Have you looked at the result of `data_mapping.get(sheet)` in your debugger?  Since you are getting your counts by calling `len()` on the result of that expression, you should be able to look at that data structure and see how its contents differs from what you expect. I assume that you'll see the issue by looking at the very beginning or end of that structure.

Comment: The 1st row in the excel has been read as header, use `header=None` to escape if there's no header. You can also specify `skip` if data doesn't start from 1st line.

Comment: @Psidom Looks like `header=None` works! All sheets align except for my first sheet which does has a header on row 3.. not sure how to handle that as my other sheets have no headers.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no headers in the Excel sheets, then the issue might be that the sheets contain an extra row of data that is not being counted by `len(data_mapping.get(sheet))`. One possibility is that the sheets contain an extra empty row at the end, which is not being counted because it doesn't contain any data.

To account for this, you can check if the last row of the dataframe is empty and subtract 1 from the row count if it is. Here's how you can modify the code to do this:

```
row_counts = []
for sheet in list(data_mapping.keys()):
    df = data_mapping.get(sheet)
    # check if the last row is empty
    if df.iloc[-1].isnull().all():
        # subtract 1 from the row count if the last row is empty
        row_counts.append(len(df) - 1)
    else:
        # use the full row count if the last row is not empty
        row_counts.append(len(df))
    print(row_counts[-1])
```

This should give you the correct row count for each sheet.

Comment: thank you for this! this effectively lowered my row counts by 1!